# Help with simplexml / libxml

Tags: apache2, php, webmin

The owner of the business I work for just upgraded one of our servers to 16.04, and since then, `simplexml` isn't working anymore.

The error I see in the apache logs is:

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function simplexml_load_string()

I'm seeing the following when I run `php -i`:

> php: /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2: no version information available (required by php)
>   /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2 is a symlink to libxml2.so.2.7.2 in the same directory (/usr/local/lib).

According to `webmin`, the package currently installed is `libxml2.so.2.9.4`.
I'm not a Linux guru by any means, but our PHP code needs `simplexml`, so I need to get this fixed.

Can anyone give any input on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I finally figured this out after a lot of research and trial/error.

`/usr/local/lib/libxml2.so` and `/usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2` were both symlinks to `/usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2.7.2`

The correct version of libxml to use was 2.9.4, which was installed at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.4`

I removed the symlinks (see below)

```
 sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so
 sudo rm /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2
```

then recreated the symlinks, pointing to the correct version

```
 sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.4 /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so
 sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.9.4 /usr/local/lib/libxml2.so.2
```

Once I did this, and restarted Apache, it worked correctly.

And here I was thinking that DLL hell only existed in Windows ;)